# Passing Array to doInBackground function and get result from it?

Tags: php, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

I want to pass an array to doInbackground() function and get results from that. actually i don't know how to pass the array to PhP file and how to search that in database. Please if you don't want to help don't make it duplicate or make others not to help me.
here is code what i have tried.

first i get the values from server database and parse it and want to store it in array. 
WHOLE FRAGMENT CODE

```
public class eventsFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView imageView;
ListView listEvents;
private TextView noevents;
SessionManager session;
String JSONString, json_string;
ArrayList<String> json_string1;

JSONObject jsonObject;
AdapterOwnEvents adapterOwnEvents;
JSONArray jsonArray;


public eventsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, container, false);
    listEvents = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listEvents1);
    noevents = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noEvents);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SearchFriends();
}

public void SearchFriends() {
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    String user_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
    new BackgroundSearch().execute(user_id);

}

class BackgroundSearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String search_url;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        search_url = "http://www.example.com/friendList.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String user_id = params[0];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(search_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_id, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSONString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(JSONString).append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        json_string = result;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

            int count = 0;
            String friend_id;
            ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                friend_id = JO.getString("friend_id");
                array1.add(friend_id);

                count++;
            }
            new BackgroundSearchEvents().execute(array1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

class BackgroundSearchEvents extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, String> {
    String search_url;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        search_url = "http://www.example.com/eventList.php";
    }


    @SafeVarargs
    @Override
    protected final String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passing) {
       // ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> passed = passing[0];


        try {
            URL url = new URL(search_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
          //  int count = 0;
            String user_id;
            for (int count = 0 ; count<passing.length; count++) {
                user_id=passed.get(count);
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(user_id), "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((JSONString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    stringBuilder.append(JSONString).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
               // count++;



            }
         //   return result;
            //return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        json_string = result;
        ParseJson();
    }
}

public void ParseJson() {

    if (json_string == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Events", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
       // listEvents.setAdapter(adapterOwnEvents);
        adapterOwnEvents = new AdapterOwnEvents(getActivity(), R.layout.own_event_list);
        listEvents.setAdapter(adapterOwnEvents);
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

            int count = 0;
            String event_id, event, event_type, date, image, friend_id;
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                event_id = JO.getString("event_id");
                event = JO.getString("event");
                date = JO.getString("date");
                event_type = JO.getString("event_type");
                friend_id = JO.getString("user_id");
                image = ("http://example.com/uploads/" + friend_id + ".png");

                Own_EventListElements own_eventListElements = new Own_EventListElements(event_id, event, event_type, date, image);
                adapterOwnEvents.add(own_eventListElements);
                listEvents.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        Own_EventListElements eventsElements = (Own_EventListElements) adapterOwnEvents.getItem(position);
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SendGreetings.class);

                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                count++;
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


}
```

this is my adapter

```
public class AdapterOwnEvents extends ArrayAdapter {
List list=new ArrayList();
public AdapterOwnEvents(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}
public void add(Own_EventListElements object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    view=convertView;
    ElementsHolder elemetsHolder=new ElementsHolder();
    if (view==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.own_event_list,parent,false);
        elemetsHolder.tx_Event=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        elemetsHolder.tx_Date=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        view.setTag(elemetsHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        elemetsHolder=(ElementsHolder) view.getTag();

    }
    Own_EventListElements own_eventListElements=(Own_EventListElements)this.getItem(position);
    elemetsHolder.tx_Event.setText(own_eventListElements.getEvent());
    elemetsHolder.tx_Date.setText(own_eventListElements.getDate());

    return view;
}

static class ElementsHolder
{
    TextView tx_Event,tx_Date;
}

}
```

and here is the php file

```
$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$sql_query = "select event_id, event, event_type, date, user_id from events where user_id like '$user_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
$response = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 array_push($response,array("event_id"=>$row[0],"event"=>$row[1],"event_type"=>$row[2],"date"=>$row[3],"user_id"=>$row[4]));
}
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);
```

but it is giving me error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Please help me. thanks in advance

EDIT: 
Here is i am initialized this

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, container, false);
    ListView listEvents = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listEvents1);

    return view;
```

LOGCAT

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.bebo, PID: 17664
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.bebo.eventsFragment.ParseJson(eventsFragment.java:230)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.bebo.eventsFragment$BackgroundSearchEvents.onPostExecute(eventsFragment.java:221)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.bebo.eventsFragment$BackgroundSearchEvents.onPostExecute(eventsFragment.java:155)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
 05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
05-14 11:37:00.733 17664-17664/com.example.bebo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Its says your `ListView` is **null**. Where is the code of `setAdapter()` to List ??

Comment: but thera are values in database and please tell me how to solve it? is there any mistake in my technique to use the arrays? @jankigadhiya

Comment: @jankigadhiya setAdapter is builtin function in android studio to set the adapter for list of results

Comment: @jankigadhiya check my updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your list in **onCreate()**:

```
listEvents = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_id);
```

Change your **ParseJson()** method like this:

```
public void ParseJson() {

if (json_string == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Events", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {

    adapterOwnEvents = new AdapterOwnEvents(getActivity(), R.layout.own_event_list);
    listEvents.setAdapter(adapterOwnEvents);
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        int count = 0;
        String event_id, event, event_type, date, image, friend_id;
        while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            event_id = JO.getString("event_id");
            event = JO.getString("event");
            date = JO.getString("date");
            event_type = JO.getString("event_type");
            friend_id = JO.getString("user_id");
            image = ("http://example.com/uploads/" + friend_id + ".png");

            Own_EventListElements own_eventListElements = new Own_EventListElements(event_id, event, event_type, date, image);
            adapterOwnEvents.add(own_eventListElements);
            listEvents.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    Own_EventListElements eventsElements = (Own_EventListElements) adapterOwnEvents.getItem(position);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SendGreetings.class);

                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            count++;
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

> Try Making your ListView Global
>
> EDIT : call `SearchFriends()` in **onCreateView()**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed, container, false);
    listEvents = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listEvents1);
    noevents = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noEvents);
    SearchFriends();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but its not working . showing the same error again

Comment: where are you initializing `listEvents` ?? It's listview right ?? share that code.. You are doing `findViewById()` ??

Comment: yes check it my updated question i added this in last

Comment: declare your list as global `ListView listEvents`. Means above onCreateView() just after the your pulic Fragment.

Comment: Check my update question. i have shared all my fragment code

Comment: what the problem with that?? The ListView is null because `onCreate()` calls before `onCreateView()`. **I m sure this will solve the problem just try it once**. It may not worked before because your ListView was not **Global**.

Comment: I have tried this now. when you updated your answer but its not working :(

Comment: i think there is error when i passed the array to doinBackground or to php file or anywhere else but i am unable to find that error

Comment: please make sure you have called `SearchFriends();` after the initialization of list. i.e. after the line `listEvents = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listEvents1);`. And if it is so i need to see your layout file `fragment_news_feed.xml`.

Comment: thank You very MUCH ... i was confused .. trying to call the layout of another fragment an listView was in second fragment.. now its solved

Comment: My pleasure. Upvoting the question will be a favor :).

Comment: you have accepted it. Upvoting means clicking on the arrow type button which shows up **^**. like this one.

Answer (score 0):

you don't set adaptor before initialize adapterOwnEvents in your ParsJson method.

```
adapterOwnEvents = new AdapterOwnEvents(getActivity(), R.layout.own_event_list);
    listEvents.setAdapter(adapterOwnEvents);
```

instead of

```
 listEvents.setAdapter(adapterOwnEvents);
    adapterOwnEvents = new AdapterOwnEvents(getActivity(), R.layout.own_event_list);
    listEvents.setAdapter(adapterOwnEvents);
```

and I suggest you to use Gson library for parsing json.

Comment: I am not getting you .. can u please explain it more?